# jquery : Multilevel navigation similiar to Orthanc Explorer

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css

I'm working on a meanjs project and I want to do something similiar as here  : https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/demo/app/explorer.html ,so basically I want to have a vertical menu, when I click on elment I want that element move to left and display the content in the middle. it's like  exploring folders but with displaying the  path of the tree on the left while I'm exploreing  the menu

please any suggestions,to achieve such a result, would be appreciated.

Comment: Website seems down. Can you provide another example please?

Comment: here is another demo  :http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/